# where nginx set the $_SERVER['HOSTNAME'] 's value?

Tags: php, nginx

I can get the  `$_SERVER['HOSTNAME']` value in **PHP CLI**, but in nginx , The value I get is empty, `phpinfo()` shows "no value".
How can I get the value in nginx?

Comment: hey you are running on php cli(command line interface) so you cant get hostname because it is not a server ! , in nginx if you are using fastcgi  then you can set in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

Comment: in develop machine I can get the value ,with the same /fastcgi_params , in the online machine ,I get empty.

Comment: check this out http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24hostname you  can set in fastcgiparams using `$hostname` variable

Comment: @Strik3r, pls answer, if you know : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332494/serverremote-port-not-giving-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set in **fastcgiparams** using `$hostname` variable.

check this out [wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24hostname](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24hostname)